# Google Cloud Monitoring: Extract Alerting Policy status using code

Tags: c#, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

### Background

I have created an alerting policy with 3 conditions. If ANY of those conditions was above the threshold - an incident created.

### Target

I'm using C# code to extract the current status of the alerting policy. My goal is to know if this alert policy has an running incident.

### Question

Is this possible to check if has running incident connected to my alert policy?

Something like:

```
static void GetPolicy(string projectId, string alertId)
{
    var client = AlertPolicyServiceClient.Create();
    var requestedPolicy = client.GetAlertPolicy(alertId);
    bool hasIncident = requestedPolicy.IsLiveIncident; // pseudo code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the alert policy object you'd be retrieving:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#AlertPolicy

From what I can tell, there's no way to know whether a policy is currently generating an incident.

Comment: Thanks for reply Yuri. But, this is sound a little bit strange that monitoring system not exposing information about running incident. Hope that Google will implement it sometime.